# NetLogo: getting a patch-set to exclude patches held in turtle's memory

Tags: netlogo

I'm modeling territory selection in NetLogo. As a turtle builds a territory, it also builds a memory of undesirable patches (an agent-set called "blacklist"), and needs to then avoid these patches while selecting new patches for the territory. In deciding on the next patch to claim, a new patch-set is created called "available-destinations," from which "highest-value" is reported based on a couple of factors (see below). I'd like available-destinations to check whether patches are part of the turtle's blacklist, and exclude those patches. I'm having trouble figuring out how to call up the turtle's blacklist while in a patch procedure, however. Any recommendations? Thanks in advance!

**Here is my main code:**

```
patches-own
[
  owner  ;; turtle who claims patch for territory
  benefit  ;; i.e., food
  avoiding ;; turtle who is avoiding this patch
]

turtles-own
[
  start-patch  ;; my territory center
  destination  ;; my next patch to claim
  territory  ;; patches I own
  blacklist  ;; my agentset of patches to avoid
]

to pick-patch
    if patch-here = start-patch [ set destination highest-value ]
    if destination != nobody [ travel ]
end

to travel
     ;; there are a number of actions here, but the relevant one is:
     ;; check if owned, and avoid it:
     if patch-here != destination
          [ if owner != nobody  ;; if it's owned...
            [ if owner != self  ;; and not by me...
              [ avoid-obstacle
                move-to start-patch ]
            ]
          ]
end

to avoid-obstacle
     ask destination [ set avoiding myself ]
     set blacklist (patches with [avoiding = myself])
end

to-report highest-value            ;; <--- source of error since using "blacklist"
     let available-destinations edge-patches with [blacklist != myself]  
     report max-one-of available-destinations ([benefit-to-me / cost-to-me]) 
end

to-report benefit-to-me
     report mean [benefit] of patches in-radius 2 
end

to-report cost-to-me
     report distance [start-patch] of myself 
end

to-report edge-patches
     report (patch-set [neighbors4] of territory) with [owner = nobody] 
end
```

This code results in this error from the reporter of highest-value: *this code can't be run by a patch, only a turtle--error while turtle 0 running BLACKLIST*. How can I fix this?

---

**My alternative idea was as follows:** use the patch-variable "avoiding":

```
to-report highest-value
     let available-destinations edge-patches with [avoiding != myself]  
     report max-one-of available-destinations ([benefit-to-me / cost-to-me]) 
end
```

This runs. Trouble is, as currently designed under the "avoid-obstacle" procedure, patches know avoiding as a single turtle and this gets overwritten if multiple turtles decide to avoid the patch.

So, avoiding should also be a patch-set if I am going to use it instead of the turtle's memory. I haven't been able to determine how to code it this way, however. I've tried this:

```
to avoid-obstacle
      ask destination
        [ let now-avoiding myself
          set avoiding (turtle-set avoiding now-avoiding) ]   
      set blacklist (patch-set blacklist patches with [avoiding = myself])            
end
```

Avoiding does appear to become a turtle-set. The turtle's memory of blacklist never gets completed correctly, however--it stays empty. Plus, the highest-value reporter doesn't appear to exclude the patches even though the agent-set avoiding contains the turtle. So, I'm at a loss.

---

**Conclusion:** I'd prefer to go with my original method of calling up the turtle's blacklist, if there is a way to do that. In case I decide to go the alternative route, I'm also curious to know what I'm doing wrong in my idea of using "avoiding". Thanks!

And a quick related question: how can I call up an agent-set to show the list of agents within it? I'd like to do this to check that the code is working as intended. From the command center, "show [blacklist] of turtle 0" only returns "(agentset, 50 patches)" rather than the list of those 50 patches, which is what I actually want to see.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `member?` to do what you want to exclude your patches? Eg:

```
to-report highest-value           
     let available-destinations edge-patches with [ member? self blacklist = false ]  
     report max-one-of available-destinations ([benefit-to-me / cost-to-me]) 
end
```

I can't really test that without your setup and everything, but `member?` reports true if the asking agent (in this case, *not* the turtle but the potentially available patch) belongs to the agentset. For a simple working example, see:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patches with [pxcor > 0 ] [
    set pcolor white
  ]
  crt 1 
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    let blacklist patches with [ pcolor = black ]
    let northpatches patches with [ pycor > 0 ]
    let northred ( northpatches with [ member? self blacklist = false ] )
    ask northred [ set pcolor red ]
    ask northred [
      print self
    ]
  ]
end
```

As far as just showing which patches are available, check out how in the above procedure, the turtle asks turtles in its agentset "northred" to print themselves to the console. That's one simple way!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this returns the same error, "this code can't be run by a patch, only a turtle--error while turtle 0 running MEMBER?" As before, I think this means that highest-value is in patch context, but blacklist is in turtle context, right? How to get around this?

Comment: Yep, you're right- that won't work. I think that if you're set on using a reporter in that way, that reporter will always query patches. However, since your reporter is a very simple two lines, you could just not use it (I don't see the need especially since it is, as far as I can tell, always turtle-specific)- just put those lines in your turtle movement procedure for simplicity. Check out the code in [this toy version of your model](https://lukepc.github.io/example_patch_choose.html) for an example. It almost certainly won't run in your browser, you'll have to download or copy/paste it.